# Scala string formating exercises error: not compiling

Tags: scala

I am working on the exercises from https://www.scala-exercises.org/std_lib/formatting

For the following question, m answer seems incorrect but I do not know why.

```
val c = 'a' //unicode for a
val d = '\141' //octal for a
val e = '\"'
val f = '\\'

"%c".format(c) should be("a") //my answers
"%c".format(d) should be("a")
"%c".format(e) should be(")
"%c".format(f) should be(\)
```

Comment: Best advise: https://github.com/scala-exercises/exercises-stdlib 1. Clone it 2. Install/run sbt

Answer (score 2):

your answer should be enclosed in quotes

```
"%c".format(e) should be("\"")
"%c".format(f) should be("\\")
```

because it wouldn't recognize string unless it's enclosed in quotes

Answer (score 0):

Check quote signs.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_strings.htm

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html

https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/scala/

You can run Scala code online and check yourself here:

https://scastie.scala-lang.org

https://ideone.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your last two lines are invalid Scala code and cannot be compiled:

```
// These are wrong
"%c".format(e) should be(")
"%c".format(f) should be(\)
```

The `be()` function needs to be passed a String, and neither of those calls are being passed a String. A String needs to start and end with a double-quote (there are some exceptions).

```
// In this case you started a String with a double-quote, but you are never
// closing the string with a second double-quote
"%c".format(e) should be(")  

// In this case you are missing both double-quotes
"%c".format(f) should be(\)
```

In this case the code should be:

```
"%c".format(e) should be("\"")
"%c".format(f) should be("\\")
```

If you want a character to be treated literally in a String, you need to "escape" it with a backslash.  So if you want to literally show a double-quote, you need to prefix it with a backslash:

```
\"
```

And as a String:

```
"\""
```

Similarily for a backslash:

```
\\
```

As a String:

```
"\\"
```

Using an IDE makes this easier to see.  Using IntelliJ the String is green but the special non-literal characters are highlighted in orange.

[image]